# Translating Java's Class Object to Delphi's Jlang_Class

Tags: java, android, delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I am working with [android.hardware.camera2.params.StreamConfigurationMap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/params/StreamConfigurationMap.html) object in a Delphi (10.2 Tokyo) application. I need to call the `getOutputSizes` function. The Java2OP tool has created the interface that looks like:

```
function getOutputSizes(klass: Jlang_Class): TJavaObjectArray<Jutil_Size>; cdecl; overload;
```

In Java the call looks like `map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class);` In Delphi, I have created an instance of the ***StreamConfigurationMap*** object from the [CameraCharacteristics](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html) instance like this:

```
map := TJStreamConfigurationMap.Wrap((mCameraCharacteristics.get(TJCameraCharacteristics.JavaClass.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP) as ILocalObject).GetObjectID);
```

And in order to call the getOutputSizes function I am doing this:

```
availableSizes := map.getOutputSizes(TJlang_Class.JavaClass.forName(StringToJString('SurfaceTexture')));
```

is `TJlang_Class.JavaClass.forName(StringToJString('SurfaceTexture'))` the best translation for `SurfaceTexture.class` in Java?

Thank you
Sam

Comment: Almost. `forName()` requires a fully qualified name, so you would need to use `'android.graphics.SurfaceTexture'` instead.

Comment: That being said, if you have a `TJSurfaceTexture` class using Embarcadero's JNI bridge framework, it has a public static `GetClsID()` method that returns a `Pointer` to the raw JNI class reference (specifically, it is a `jobject` returned by JNI's `NewGlobalRef()` function). I wonder if you can somehow convert that to a `Jlang_Class`? Maybe `TJlang_Class.Wrap()` will work? Look at the source code in `$(BDS)\source\rtl\android\Androidapi.JNIBridge.pas` to see how the bridge framework uses JNI class references, it might give you some ideas